# pthread_cond_signal and pthread_cond_wait, error check

Tags: c, pthreads

I wanted to understands, what happens when a thread_1 sends pthread_cond_signal multiple times to a thread_2(waiting on pthread_cond_wait) which has already received a signal and still in progress.

1. Will thread_1 block until signal is processed?
2. OR Will the signal be ignored at thread_2 and thread_1 continues its execution

In either of above cases, can we get any error messages so that we can take appropriate action (like return appropriate error in thread1)

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to understands, what happens when a thread_1 sends
>   pthread_cond_signal multiple times to a thread_2(waiting on
>   pthread_cond_wait) which has already received a signal and still in
>   progress.

You can't do that in the first place.  `pthread_cond_signal` performs an operation on a condition variable; it does not signal any specific thread.  I'll suppose you mean to ask about what happens when a thread calls 
`pthread_cond_signal`, specifying a CV that has no waiters at that point.

> 1. Will thread_1 block until signal is processed?
> 2. OR Will the signal be ignored at thread_2 and thread_1 continues its execution

The latter. `pthread_cond_signal` should not be construed as attempting to send a message to any particular thread.  If anything is being messaged it is the kernel, or through it the CV.  In any case, if such a call is performed while no threads are waiting on the specified CV, then it has no effect.  It certainly does not block the calling thread.

> In either of above cases, can we get any error messages so that we can
>   take appropriate action (like return appropriate error in thread1)

No, because it is not an error to signal a CV that has no waiters.  If you're looking to perform some kind of synchronous message exchange then you can do that on top of a mutex and CV, but by themselves those do not provide what you want.